# Why the terminal downloads things so slow?

Tags: gnome-terminal, downloads

I observed that everytime when I download something using `apt` it usually downloads below 1mbps, but my internet speed is like 1gbps(700-800 mbps) using wireless connection. How can I allow more bandwidth?

Comment: Probably the repository server it downloads stuff from does not offer you more bandwidth. Try switching to a mirror server close to your location to get optimal speed.

Comment: Well I guess, "ro.archive.ubuntu.com" means that the server is in Romania beacuse of the `ro` right? Beacuse I live in Romania, so I presume that I should get a faster speed

Comment: Actually nevermind, I checked the second answer from that quesiton, and I selected another server and everything is smooth now.